# How does printf compile in ANSI-C (varargs)

Tags: c, printf, ansi-c

How does gcc manage to compile printf in ANSI-C?

Every printf prototype I saw used varargs, but that is not supported in ANSI-C eg:

```
int (*)(const char *, ...)
```

Is there a trick to it, if so can we use it for our code in ANSI-C?

Comment: What do you mean by "ANSI C"? This is a very imprecise term, unfortunately. I assume you mean [C89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#ANSI_C_and_ISO_C), which certainly has varargs?

Comment: I mean c89/c90, it says: Variadic macros became a standard part of the C language with C99. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Comment: Variadic macros != variadic arguments

Comment: @VincentAlex Yes, but `printf()` is a variadic *function*, not a macro.

Comment: Good to know they are handled separately, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assumptions are all wrong.

First, there is nothing called "ANSI-C" after the year 1990. Americans may refer to the C standard as INCITS/ISO/IEC 9899:2011, but nobody outside the US cares. We just call it ISO C.

The C language has (unfortunately) always supported variadic functions, for the past 40 years or so. In order to code the function definition, you need to include `stdarg.h`.

You are confusing this with variadic *macros*, which were introduced in the year 1999 (C99).